# Display content based on URL

Tags: apache, url-rewriting

In my site I had a desire to make simpler URLs such as:
`http://www.example.com/about`

Instead of:
`http://www.example.com/about.php`

Mostly for aesthetics, for now I have Apache redirect to `./default.php` if a directory is requested. However this forces me to create a directory at
`http://www.example.com/about/` and a file inside it called `default.php` ending up with:
`http://www.example.com/about/default.php`

I know there's a better way, probably using PHP or JS, what do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's all in apache's configs,
rewriteEngine can do that for you

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html

http://alexcican.com/post/how-to-remove-php-html-htm-extensions-with-htaccess/

---

*A snippet taken from third link:*
To remove the .php extension from a PHP file for example yoursite.com/wallpaper.php to yoursite.com/wallpaper you have to add the following code to your Apache config:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

If you want to remove the .html extension:

```
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

That’s it! You can even link pages inside the HTML document without needing to add the extension of the page. For example:

```
<a href="http://whatever.com/wallpaper" title="wallpaper">wallpaper</a>
```